# Ruby returning null when printing same string again

Tags: ruby, git

I am modifying a pre-receive hook of gitlab

the code which returns branch name is

```
print ARGF.read
print "\n"
refs = ARGF.read
print refs
```

first time when i do print or puts i get the branch name but again second time whenever i use the same string it returns nothing. nil or empty string.

Any clue why is this happening. I am new to ruby, so unable to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARGF is a stream designed for use in scripts that process files given as command-line arguments or passed in via STDIN.

The manual states that [ARGF::read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-read)

*Reads _length_ bytes from ARGF. The files named on the command line
are concatenated and treated as a single file by this method, so when
called without arguments the contents of this pseudo file are returned in
their entirety.*

You might want to use [ARGF::readline](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-readline)

*Returns the next line from the current file in ARGF.*

or maybe [ARGF::rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-rewind)

*Positions the current file to the beginning of input, resetting ARGF.lineno to zero.*

Answer (score 2):

A call `ARGF.read` is not idempotent, that is you cannot invoke it many times and expect the same result as it will "consume" all the command line arguments passed to your hook.

If you want to reuse the command line arguments you have to first store them in a local variable and then do what you want with them

```
refs = ARGF.read
print refs
print "\n"
# do something here with your arguments
print "\n"
```